# Can't make delete button using $_GET method

Tags: php, html, html-table, http-get

I got my first study task to make a script. Task is the following: Create a webform for uploading files, after file upload they are displayed on the same page in html table. This is my very first task and my priority is just to make it work. So I created a form and function to scan upload folder for files and then put them in array. Afterwards array is used in a cucle that builds up an html table. Please help me to build correct delete button, as I just can't get it to work. My code is here:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['action']=='delete' && isset($_GET['file'])) {
        unlink($dir.$filelist[$i]);
        echo "File ".$filelist[$i]. " has been removed";
}
 
 
//table with files
echo"<table border=1 cellpading=5 cellspasing=0>
<tr><th>#</th><th>Filename</th><th>Path</th><th>File extenstion</th><TH>File Size<th>Remove file?</th></tr>";
for ($i=0; $i <count($fileslist) ; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo"<td>$i</td><td>". $fileslist[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=".$dir.$fileslist[$i].">".$fileslist[$i]."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$ext=pathinfo(($dir.$fileslist[$i]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$size= filesize_get($dir.$fileslist[$i])."</td>";
        echo "<td> <a href=\"upload.php?action=delete&file=".$filelist[$i].">Delete </a></td>";
        echo "<tr>";
}
echo"</tabe>";
```

Get following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\PHP(1)\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: filelist in D:\PHP(1)\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 47

Comment: looking at your first lines, in the delete context, you are using $i which is not defined at this point and it won't work as expected for this reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo "<td> <a href=\"upload.php?action=delete&file=".$filelist[$i].">Delete </a></td>";
```

by

```
echo "<td> <a href=\"upload.php?action=delete&file=".$fileslist[$i].">Delete </a></td>";
```

You're just missing the s in fileslist

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take that error message very literally.  Your variable `$filelist` is not defined in the code sample you provided.

Also your first error is being thrown because you try to check `$_GET['action'] == 'deleted'` even in case where that parameter is not passed via GET.  You should always check for the existence of the parameter before using it in comparison like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='delete' && isset($_GET['file'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You are deleting the $i-th item when $i isn't defined yet

2- As said in above answers

To prevent errors in variable and function names, you may use a text editor that supports code completion. For example, a very light tool that can help is [Geany](http://www.geany.org/Main/About). I still use this one even on big projects, on both linux and windows. It won't use a lot of RAM and CPU and won't take time to open.

In a AND (&&) condition block, conditions are read from left to right and the block will break as soon as something is not true, so you more likely want to test critical stuff first so it won't get in trouble further in the block.